# Order of commit in Hibernate merge

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I use hibernate merge to commit my data in DB. Is it possible to alter the order of commit in the merge?

I have three entity classes - EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYEE_DETAILS and EMPLOYEE_RELATION. EMPLOYEE is the parent table for other two and EMPLOYEE_DETAILS and EMPLOYEE_RELATION has no relation among them. As of now the commit happens in the order -

```
 EMPLOYEE-->EMPLOYEE_DETAILS-->EMPLOYEE_RELATION.
```

But i want commit to happen in the order -

```
 EMPLOYEE-->EMPLOYEE_RELATION-->EMPLOYEE_DETAILS.
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the reason for it ?

Comment: The commit should happen once, as your code exits the transaction boundary. Hibernate will insert/update records into the database as it sees fit.

Comment: The commit of data is ok, but i want to change the order of commit.

Comment: As per @EngineerDollery, the commit is an atomic operation. The data is either all updated together, or not at all. You seem to be concerned with the ordering of the UPDATE operations? These do not commit your data until the transaction completes.